# Retrieving Rows Returned for a query from Redshift System Tables

Tags: rows, resultset, amazon-redshift

Is there a query I can run against one of the system query log tables that will tell me how many records Redshift returned to the user for a particular query - ie. the final result set row count?

I am thinking it is in the svl_query_summary table - but I am not sure how to get the row with the actual results that were returned to the user vs. the rows that were just used in one of the many steps.

Thanks,

T. Thompson